# not to be inspired by its promise and its example

Tags: negation, infinitives, clauses, complements

> I defy any person to travel to this great country at any time and **not to be inspired** by its promise and its example. - from Theresa May’s speech to Republicans in Philadelphia

What is the grammar and part of speech that use here "not to be inspired"?

Comment: Does this help? http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23152/order-of-not-with-infinitive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two infinitive clauses (to travel.....not to be inspired by) are complements of **defy anyone**.

**(not) to be inspired by its promise** is a passive form. **promise** is that which inspires **any person**, the direct object of **defy**, the main verb.

The pattern is

```
I defy someone to do X
and
not to experience Y after doing so
```

The generic statement can be paraphrased "I believe experience Y is unavoidable if you do X.